# Heroku error while deploying. error: RPC failed; HTTP 504 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 504

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I had no problems in the past with the deployment to Heroku via HTTP transport, but recently I am unable to deploy.

This is the error I am getting:

```
Enumerating objects: 58668, done.
Counting objects: 100% (57434/57434), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (16705/16705), done.
Writing objects: 100% (57124/57124), 50.77 MiB | 76.23 MiB/s, done.
Total 57124 (delta 44149), reused 52353 (delta 40249)
error: RPC failed; HTTP 504 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 504
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've tried switching to SSH transport and it works, but Heroku is retiring SSH transport, so I need to figure out this error.

Also I tried to change the postBuffer according to [atlassian's page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-push-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-779171796.html), but I got the error again.

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this? There are very few resources on the web that I found, and none of them are fixing the problem.

Comment: 504 is a "gateway timeout": some middleman somewhere thought you were taking too long and cut you off. You have only a few options: go faster—probably not actually possible—or do something about the middleman. Find out who this middleman is. If possible, remove him entirely. If not possible, get him to increase his timeout.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I raised a support ticket to Heroku and the answer was to reset the Git repo

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
heroku repo:reset -a <app-name>
```

After I did this, I had no problems with the deployment

Comment: This also gave me a 504 error.

Comment: The first time I ran heroku repo:reset -a <app-name> I got `Expected response to be successful, got 504a, ran them both again, and it has worked. Good result, but more than one attempt could be required.